# imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error

```
imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:
```

everytime I try to upload a photo. I used it for months and never a problem, now suddenly I get it.

I tried with different photos and to free space on disk but nothing.

```
private function watermark($destination, $name, $path){
      $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
      $stamp = imagecreatefrompng(public_path('/watermark.png'));
      $marge_right = 50;
      $marge_bottom = 50;
      $fixed_width = 768;
      $fixed_height = 531;

      $rate_x = $fixed_width/imagesx($im);
      $rate_y = $fixed_height/imagesy($im);

      $sx = imagesx($stamp);
      $sy = imagesy($stamp);
      imagecopyresized($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0,imagesx($stamp)/$rate_x, imagesy($stamp)/$rate_y, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($im, $destination.'/'.$name);
      imagedestroy($im);
    }
```

Please help me. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: how much disk space do you have available to /tmp?

Comment: a lot, I'm getting this problem on localhost. Production is fine.

Comment: @Lino so what has changed in your localhost, when (or before) you started getting this error?

Comment: related to photos I just changed only size. Genrellay I chnaged the form submission, but didn't touch that part.

Comment: Check your max upload size and available memory.

Comment: max upload 2000M, available memory 480G

Comment: 480G of Available Memory?! Max upload 2G?!

Comment: yeah, it's localhost